# EF Core SqlLite: Updating many-to-many entity stuck between "UNIQUE constraint failed" or "another instance is already being tracked"

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor

This feels like a very basic issue, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. I have a very basic many-to-many relationship between two classes:

```
public class Video
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

This is enough for EF to automatically create three tables: `Videos`, `Tags` and a joining table `TagVideo`.

After adding a tag to a video, I want to save the changes:

```
public void SaveVideo(Video video)
{
    using var db = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    db.Videos.Update(video);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

(this is a Blazor server app and I am using DbContextFactory to create a new db context for each operation as suggested in the Blazor docs)

When adding the first tag to a video, this works fine. EF starts tracking the video and related entities:

```
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:29:25.375 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Video' entity with key '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:29:25.379 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Tag' entity with key '{Id: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c}'.
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:29:25.390 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'TagVideo' entity with key '{TagsId: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c, VideosId: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
```

and successfully creates the row in the TagVideo joining table. So far so good.

The issue is when I try to add a second tag.

EF is now tracking one video, two tags, and two joins, one of which is already stored in the DB:

```
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:37:41.089 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Video' entity with key '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:37:41.089 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Tag' entity with key '{Id: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c}'.
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:37:41.089 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Tag' entity with key '{Id: eb5794cc-ced4-4096-b3fd-963eaacb88e9}'.
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:37:41.090 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'TagVideo' entity with key '{TagsId: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c, VideosId: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
dbug: 13/02/2022 13:37:41.090 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'TagVideo' entity with key '{TagsId: eb5794cc-ced4-4096-b3fd-963eaacb88e9, VideosId: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
```

Now on `SaveChanges()`, I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: TagVideo.TagsId, TagVideo.VideosId'.

i.e. EF is trying to insert both `TagVideo` entities, even though one already exists.

I know that this is something to do with EF not knowing about the `TagVideo` entity that already exists in the DB, and that I need to attach it to the context somehow.

This is where I get lost.

I've tried attaching every single tag and related video to the context:

```
public class UpdateVideo(Video video)
{
    using var db = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    var tags = db.Tags.Include(v => v.Videos).ToList();

    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        db.Tags.Attach(tag);
    }

    db.Videos.Update(video);
    db.SaveChanged();
}
```

But now I get a new error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Video' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

i.e. EF is now getting confused between the Video entity passed as a parameter to the UpdateVideo method and the entity retrieved from the database.

I've tried a lot of random combinations that I won't bore you with, but whatever I do I always get one of these two errors: "Unique constraint failed", or "another instance is already being tracked".

How do I tell the context about the rows that already exist in the TagVideo joining table so that it stops trying to insert them as new rows?

Or more generally: how do I save a change in a many-to-many relationship to the database?

## Update

Here's a bit more info after trying Henk's suggestion below.

New method:

```
   public void UpdateVideo(Video video)
    {
        using var db = _dbcf.CreateDbContext();
        foreach (var tag in video.Tags)
        {
            db.Tags.Attach(tag);
        }
        db.Videos.Update(video);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Starting with a Video with no Tags, here is what EF reports after adding the first Tag:

After the `foreach` loop:

```
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Tag' entity with key '{Id: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c}'.
```

After `db.Videos.Update(video)`:

```
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Video' entity with key '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'TagVideo' entity with key '{TagsId: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c, VideosId: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
```

After `db.SaveChanges()`:

```
INSERT Into "TagVideo" [...]
UPDATE "Videos" [...]
The 'Video' entity with key '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}' tracked by 'AppDbContext' changed state from 'Modified' to 'Unchanged'.
The 'TagVideo' entity with key '{TagsId: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c, VideosId: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}' tracked by 'AppDbContext' changed state from 'Added' to 'Unchanged'.
```

The new row is successfully added to the TagVideo table.

Now here is the result of each command after adding a second Tag:

After `foreach`

```
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Tag' entity with key '{Id: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c}'.
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Video' entity with key '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'Tag' entity with key '{Id: eb5794cc-ced4-4096-b3fd-963eaacb88e9}'.
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'TagVideo' entity with key '{TagsId: 5b10e518-b2e6-4828-a5bb-8e725b7dc84c, VideosId: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
Context 'AppDbContext' started tracking 'TagVideo' entity with key '{TagsId: eb5794cc-ced4-4096-b3fd-963eaacb88e9, VideosId: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}'.
```

After `db.Videos.Update(video)`

```
The 'Video' entity with key '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}' tracked by 'AppDbContext' changed state from 'Unchanged' to 'Modified'.
```

After `db.SaveChanges()`

```
UPDATE "Videos" [...]
The 'Video' entity with key '{Id: 275018be-6e34-4059-aca1-31c39fb9efe9}' tracked by 'AppDbContext' changed state from 'Modified' to 'Unchanged'.
```

No new row is inserted.

I don't understand why in the first instance the context starts tracking the new TagVideo entity after the `db.Videos.Update` command, and in the second instance it starts tracking it after the `foreach`?